# Custom list of lists into dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have list of lists and I wish to create a dictionary with length of each element as values. I tried the following:

```
tmp = [['A', 'B', 'E'], ['B', 'E', 'F'], ['A', 'G']]
tab = []
for line in tmp:
    tab.append(dict((k, len(tmp)) for k in line))
```

But it gives the output as:

```
[{'A': 3, 'B': 3, 'E': 3}, {'B': 3, 'E': 3, 'F': 3}, {'A': 3, 'G': 3}]
```

What is the modification that I should make to get the output:

```
{['A', 'B', 'E']:3, ['B', 'E', 'F']:3, ['A', 'G']:2}
```

Thanks in advance.

AP

Comment: You can't have a list as the key

Comment: @Farhan.K. Ok. When I tried, tab.append(dict((len(tmp),k) for k in line)); I got ~[<generator object <genexpr> at 0x1041e81e0>, <generator object <genexpr> at 0x1041e8370>, <generator object <genexpr> at 0x1041e8320>]~. What does this mean ?

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `list` objects as dictionary keys, they are mutable and unhashable. You can convert them to tuple. Also note that you are looping over each sub list. You can use a generator expression by only looping over the main list:

```
In [3]: dict((tuple(sub), len(sub)) for sub in tmp)
Out[3]: {('A', 'B', 'E'): 3, ('A', 'G'): 2, ('B', 'E', 'F'): 3}
```

Comment: @Arun I don't know what your use case is, but if you want to ignore the order of elements in the keys to your dictionary, you should use frozenset instead of tuple.

Answer (score 1):

```
{tuple(t):len(t) for t in tmp}
```

Input :

```
[['A', 'B', 'E'], ['B', 'E', 'F'], ['A', 'G']]
```

Output :

```
{('A', 'G'): 2, ('A', 'B', 'E'): 3, ('B', 'E', 'F'): 3}
```

Dictionnary does not accept list as key, but tuple